# SSL Socket Python non blocking

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, ssl, nonblocking

I made a client-server communication on python3. It works well, the server is able to serve more than one client, all have openssl-import and use threading.

What I want for now: They should be able to use openSSL and while receiving something on the socket (server AND client) they should be able to send something WHILE receiving data (e.g. call 'count' from the client and after that type something else while getting the serveranswer). But when I run my code, every time (while receiving on the client side) when I want to send something it recognized in the end what I tried to send. Hard to explain (my english is not the best). 
What am I doing wrong? Shall I have to make all sockets to "non-blocking-mode"?
Maybe you can check this out:

**the server:**

```
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::#
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::        MULTITHREAD + SSL       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::#
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ server.py ] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::#
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::#
#TODO: logs, try-exp

import socket as socketlib
import ssl
from threading import Thread
from time import ctime #formatiertes datetime nutzen!
import logging
import time


HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4200

AUTHENTICATIONS = {'fin': 'finja',
                   'haxe': '1337',
                   'hell': 'd404559f602eab6fd602ac7680dacbfaadd13630335e951f097af3900e9de176b6db28512f2e000b9d04fba5133e8b1c6e8df59db3a8ab9d60be4b97cc9e81db'
                   }

logging.basicConfig(filename="log.log", level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s - %(name)s :  - LINE_%(lineno)s (%(funcName)s) # PROCESS ID %(process)s >>> THREAD ID %(thread)s\n || %(message)s \n')



def manage_client(connstream, client_socket, addr):
    print("~~ Step 6/6 successful [Server started admitted request in new thread (Client {})] ~~".format(addr))
    logging.debug("~~ Step 6/6 successful [Server started admitted request in new thread (Client %s)] ~~", addr)
    connstream.sendall(b'Server accepted the connection!')

    usr_accepted = False
    while True:
        data = connstream.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
        print("Client {}: ".format(addr), data)
        logging.debug("Client %s: %s", addr, data)
        if data == 'exit':
            disconnect(connstream, addr)
            break
        elif data == "show status":
            if usr_accepted:
                show_status(connstream)
        elif data == "username":
            usr_accepted = authentication(connstream, addr)
            if not usr_accepted:
                disconnect(connstream, addr)
                break
            continue
        elif data == "count":
            for i in range(1, 10):
                connstream.sendall(str(i).encode("utf-8"))
                time.sleep(3)
        try:
            #connstream.sendall(b'Servertestmessage')
            pass
        except BrokenPipeError as e:
            print(e)
            logging.debug(e)
            logging.exception('Got exception here')
            print("MESSAGE COULD NOT BE SEND!")
            logging.debug("MESSAGE COULD NOT BE SEND!")
            connstream.close()
            break


def authentication(connstream, addr):
    usr_name = connstream.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
    usr_pwd = connstream.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
    if usr_name in AUTHENTICATIONS:
        auth_pwd = AUTHENTICATIONS[usr_name]
        if auth_pwd == usr_pwd:
            connstream.send(b'Authentication succeeded!')
            logging.debug("CLIENT AUTHENTICATION FROM {} ACCEPTED".format(addr))
            return True
    connstream.send(b'Authentication failed!')
    logging.debug("CLIENT AUTHENTICATION FROM {} NOT ACCEPTED".format(addr))
    return False



def disconnect(connstream, addr):
    print("+++++ SOCKET CLOSED +++++   [Client {}]".format(addr))
    logging.debug("+++++ SOCKET CLOSED +++++   [Client {}]".format(addr))
    connstream.close()

def show_status(connstream):
    server_location_time = ctime()
    connstream.sendall(server_location_time.encode("utf-8"))
    connstream.sendall("Location: CHINA".encode("utf-8"))
    connstream.sendall("Adress: XYZ".encode("utf-8"))
    connstream.sendall("Last update: Oct-11-2019".encode("utf-8"))
    connstream.sendall("Python Version: 3".encode("utf-8"))


def main():
    try:
        context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
        context.load_cert_chain(certfile="/home/fin/server.crt", keyfile="/home/fin/server.key")
        print("~~ Step 1/6 successful [Loading ssl certification]~~")
        logging.debug("~~ Step 1/6 successful [Loading ssl certification]~~")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("CERTIFICATE NOT FOUND!!")
        logging.exception("Certificate could not be loaded. Program is not running anymore. Please restart the program!")
        logging.error("Certificate could not be loaded. Program is not running anymore. Please restart the program!")

    server_socket = socketlib.socket(socketlib.AF_INET, socketlib.SOCK_STREAM)
    with server_socket:
        server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
        print("~~ Step 2/6 successful [Socket Binding IP {} on PORT {} as IPv4] ~~".format(HOST, PORT))
        logging.debug("~~ Step 2/6 successful [Socket Binding IP {} on PORT {} as IPv4] ~~".format(HOST, PORT))
        server_socket.listen()
        print("~~ Step 3/6 successful [Server is listening for requests] ~~")
        logging.debug("~~ Step 3/6 successful [Server is listening for requests] ~~")
        try:
            while True:
                    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
                    print("~~ Step 4/6 successful [Server got a request from {}] ~~".format(addr))
                    logging.debug("~~ Step 4/6 successful [Server got a request from %s] ~~", addr)
                    client_socket = context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=True)
                    print("~~ Step 5/6 successful [Request is ssl encrypted now (Client {})] ~~".format(addr))
                    logging.debug("~~ Step 5/6 successful [Request is ssl encrypted now (Client %s)] ~~", addr)

                    Thread(target=manage_client, args=(client_socket, server_socket, addr), daemon=True).start()

        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            print(e)                       
            logging.exception(e)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**and the client:**

```
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::#
#::::     MULTITHREAD + SSL    ::::#
#:::::::::: [ client.py] ::::::::::#
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::#
#TODO: logs

import socket, ssl, pprint, sys
from _thread import *
import time
import hashlib

#global msg
#msg = ''

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4200




def msg_receive(conn, IP):
    try:
        while True:
            msg = conn.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
            print("\n[{}]: {}".format(IP, msg))
            time.sleep(0.000001)
            if msg == '':
                print("LOST CONNECTION TO SERVER!")
                print("TRYING TO RECONNECT... (Refresh Browser!)") #TODO:
                conn.close()
                break
    except OSError as e:
        return


def msg_print_send(conn, IP):
    while True:
        message = input("\nNachricht: ")
        conn.sendall(message.encode("utf-8"))
        if message == 'username':
            usr_message = input("\nBN: ")
            conn.sendall(usr_message.encode("utf-8"))
            pwd_message = hashlib.sha512(bytes(input("\nPW: "), "utf-8"))
            p_message = (pwd_message.hexdigest())
            conn.sendall(p_message.encode("utf-8"))

        if message == 'exit':
            print("+++++ SOCKET CLOSED +++++")
            conn.close()
            sys.exit() #TODO: skript beendet sich nicht
            break

        #if message != '':
            #conn.sendall(message.encode("utf-8"))
    #return


def main():
    context = ssl.SSLContext()
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.check_hostname = True

    try:
        context.load_verify_locations("/home/fin/server.crt")
        print("***CHECK- Certificate loading successful")
    except (FileExistsError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
        print(e)
        print("::::: Program will be closed now! :::::")
        sys.exit()

    try:
        # with socket.create_connection((ip, port)) as s:
        conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM), server_hostname="127.0.0.1")
        print("***CHECK- Socket only supports ssl connection successful")
        try:
            conn.connect((IP, PORT))
            print("***CHECK- Connection to server successful")
            conn.sendall(b"Thanks for accepting the connection!")
            print("***CHECK- Bytestring sending successful")
        except:
            print("CONNECTION NOT POSSIBLE! IN 10 SECONDS TRYING TO CONNECT AGAIN..")
            time.sleep(10.0)
            return
    except ssl.CertificateError as e:
        # print("Error {}: {}".format(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        # print("Error {}:".format(e))  #TODO: Darf Ziel-IP bekannt sein? (Fehlerprovokation bei Hackern) SICHERHEITSMANGEL!
        print("Hostname doesn't match.")
        print("::::: Program will be closed now! :::::")
        sys.exit()
    except ConnectionError as e:
        # print("Error {}: {}".format(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        print(e)
        print("::::: Program will be closed now! :::::")
        sys.exit()

    start_new_thread(msg_receive, (conn, IP))
    start_new_thread(msg_print_send, (conn, IP))


    try:
        while 1:
            #pass
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out:
The code is working fine with ssl socket + threading.

The only mistake was in my server.py: 
For receiving + sending I only used ONE thread. So each time I want to send something, I opened a new thread. Receiving WHILE sending needs 1 thread for it's own :]
My bad.

Thanks anyway!